# Is it possible to take an Android firmware snapshot?

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware

I am currently working for a company that operates screens in some kind of 'kiosk mode' to provide information in malls etc.

The devices are basically big monitors connected to a development board (as far as I can see similar to a Raspberry Pi) which runs Android and starts a display app when boot up.

Now the problem is that we currently have to set up all the boards manually. Meaning removing certain pre-installed vendor apps, installing our own apps, setting the right configuration, etc.

Since this process is quite time-consuming and prone to errors, we thought if there is a solution to configure one device, save the "firmware" (.img) on a computer or USB stick and then use this image as a base for all other devices.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? How can we create a snapshot of the Android device?
All devices are the same from a hardware point.

Comment: You have like in other systems the choice to perform an offline backup (e.g. using a recovery ROM that support it) or an online backup using root permission while the OS is booted you can create an image accessing the block device of the flash memory.